# htaccess mod-rewrite conflict with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the htaccess file for a project that is using the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ page.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?/([^/\.]+)/?$ page.php?theme=$1&pg=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ page.php?theme=$1&pg=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?/$ page.php?theme=$1&pg=$1 [L]
```

which effectively changes `domain.com/theme/page` to `domain.com/page.php?theme=theme&pg=page`.

The problem i have is that i'm also using a wordpress install on this project, installed under `domain.com/blog`.

so, visiting `domain.com/blog` is rewriting to `domain.com/page.php?theme=blog` and breaks the wordpress install.

is there a way i can set an exception to the rewrite rule so that `domain.com/blog` will properly load the wp blog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try excluding `/blog` from being processed as follows

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#if its blog, do nothing
RewriteRule ^blog/  - [L,NC] 

#rest of your rules go here
```

Comment: this almost works. adding that means that `domain.com/blog` is loading wp, but it's loading as `domain.com/blog/?theme=blog&pg=blog` and if I try `domain.com/blog/` it doesn't work. This is also not working for the detail pages on the blog.

Answer (score 0):

Add the base at the top

```
RewriteBase /
```

And the obvious answer would just be to add a `RewriteRule ^blog/  - [L]` rule after this, but what I don't understand about your Q is that Wordpress will normally create it's own optimised `.htaccess` in the `/blog` subdirectory.  Just by the fact that rules in your DOCROOT `.htaccess` file are firing tells me that this doesn't exists, because if it did then this would be executed instead for /blog/* URIs.  Have you looked at the [WP htaccess Control](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-htaccess-control) plugin?